# Jenkins Unknown Maven lifecycle phase

Tags: maven, jenkins, build, devops, maven-plugin

```
Started by user Deepak Sharma
Running as SYSTEM
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Build
The recommended git tool is: NONE
No credentials specified

git rev-parse --resolve-git-dir /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Build/.git # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
git config remote.origin.url https://github.com/hkhcoder/vprofile-project.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/hkhcoder/vprofile-project.git
git --version # timeout=10
git --version # 'git version 2.34.1'
git fetch --tags --force --progress -- https://github.com/hkhcoder/vprofile-project.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/main^{commit} # timeout=10
Checking out Revision 3286baea423fa43386ce0cb35c480a6ffe9b949e (refs/remotes/origin/main)
git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
git checkout -f 3286baea423fa43386ce0cb35c480a6ffe9b949e # timeout=10
Commit message: "test ssh keys 43"
git rev-list --no-walk 3286baea423fa43386ce0cb35c480a6ffe9b949e # timeout=10
\[Build\] $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/MAVEN3/bin/mvn Clean Install
\[INFO\] Scanning for projects...
\[INFO\]
\[INFO\] ---------------------\< com.visualpathit:vprofile \>----------------------
\[INFO\] Building Visualpathit VProfile Webapp v2
\[INFO\]   from pom.xml
\[INFO\] --------------------------------\[ war \]---------------------------------
\[INFO\] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
\[INFO\] BUILD FAILURE
\[INFO\] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
\[INFO\] Total time:  0.184 s
\[INFO\] Finished at: 2023-11-15T02:35:02Z
\[INFO\] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
\[ERROR\] Unknown lifecycle phase "Clean". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format \<plugin-prefix\>:\<goal\> or \<plugin-group-id\>:\<plugin-artifact-id\>\[:\<plugin-version\>\]:\<goal\>. Available lifecycle phases are: pre-clean, clean, post-clean, validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy. -\> \[Help 1\]
\[ERROR\]
\[ERROR\] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
\[ERROR\] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
\[ERROR\]
\[ERROR\] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
\[ERROR\] \[Help 1\] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/LifecyclePhaseNotFoundException
Build step 'Invoke top-level Maven targets' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE

Resolution for above issue.
```

Comment: The error message clearly indicates that it does not like your Upper cased goals, try `clean install` instead of `Clean Install`, linux is case-sensitive